# Tangent line at inflection point properties

Tags: calculus

I am going through [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4344616/does-tangent-line-of-inflection-point-always-passes-through-the-curve) and I am confused at what it is even asking. The answerers seem to have to taken it as sensible though.

The OP has given an example of the function $f(x)=\sin x$ for purposes of illustrating his point. Plotting the function, I get it:

> [image]

I don't see the tangent passing through any point on the curve other than the point it is based in.

Could someone explain the characterization of the tangent at inflection point more explicitly to me?

Comment: The answer can be no more explicit than the question.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, it looks like passing through the curve is supposed to mean that, around the point, part of the curve is on one side of the tangent while another part is on another side.
Note that just like any line, a tangent divides the plane into two parts.

For all tangents to $y=x^2$, the curve lies entirely on one side of the tangent.

Let  $f(x)$ be the function, $l(x)$ be the tangent at point $a$, then "passing through" means $f(x)-l(x)$ changes sign around $a$.